# El efecto de jquery no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Codigo html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Formulario</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="login-page">
                <div class="form">
                    <form class="register-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
                        <button>create</button>
                        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
                    </form>
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                        <button>login</button>
                        <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Codigo en javascript**

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

Lo que trato de hacer es, que cuando pinche en create an account, aparezca el formulario de registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Qué comportamiento observa tu código?

Comment: Observa lo que ha comentado alanfcm en el codigo, cuando lo ejecuto aqui, funciona, el efecto ese es el que tiene que hacer, pero en webstrom, no hace nada

Comment: Recomendaría que agregues la biblioteca jQuery en el encabezado del documento, no al final del `body`
 y que uses `function`  (el sustituto de document ready), poniendo dentro todo tu código. Así aseguras no lanzar ninguna acción hasta que el DOM esté cargado, esto es particularmente importante en servidores lentos o en páginas que tardan mucho en cargar o cuando la red está saturada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltaba ocultar una de las forms asi:

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Formulario</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="login-page">
                <div class="form">
                    <form class="register-form" style="display: none">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
                        <button>create</button>
                        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
                    </form>
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                        <button>login</button>
                        <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto yo no hace nada...

Comment: A que te refieres?  Aqui funciona bien.

Comment: Si si, aqui cuando lo ejecuto está perfecto, es lo que tiene que hacer pero en el webstorm, cuando lo ejecuto, no hace nada, que es lo raro

Comment: Intenta copiar y pegar el codigo.

Comment: Nada, no quiere funcionar

Comment: En donde tienes el codigo javascript?  Intenta ponerlo despues de agregar jQuery.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora ya funciona, gracias a poner el js despues del jquery y poner lo que me ha dicho Cedano. Muchas gracias a ambos